# Bower error: ENOTFOUND Package bower-bootstrap-accordion not found

Tags: json, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

I am trying to install this plug in which is the Angular UI Bootstrap, I do not need the full library, only that plug in, and I am getting the error:

the command I am entering in the terminal:

`bower install bower-bootstrap-accordion --save`

and then the error:

`Bower error: ENOTFOUND Package bower-bootstrap-accordion not found`

here is the `bower.json`

```
{
  "name": "bower-bootstrap-accordion",
  "license": "MIT",
  "version": "0.11.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/graphs/contributors"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bower-bootstrap-collapse": "0.11.0"
  },
  "main": "ui-accordion-tpls.js"
}
```

[Link to the plugin](https://github.com/ui-bootstrap-bower-test/bower-bootstrap-accordion)

do I have to install the full library ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

bower-bootstrap-accordion is not [registered](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register) in the Bower registry and therefore the Bower client cannot find it by name.
You can use the Git repository URL when defining the dependency. This will save the Bower client the need to search for the package URL in the Bower registry.

```
"dependencies": {
  "bower-bootstrap-accordion" : "git://github.com/ui-bootstrap-bower-test/bower-bootstrap-accordion.git"
}
```

In addition this package has dependencies on additional packages such as *bower-bootstrap-collapse, bower-bootstrap-transition* which are also not registered in the Bower registry. You will have to include it in the same way in your dependencies.
I think all those packages are from the same author - https://github.com/ui-bootstrap-bower-test/