# bower install gives "Package not found"

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

I downloaded a JavaScript project from github. The project is using bower to manage dependencies.

I installed *NodeJS* and then *Bower* using `npm install bower`

However, when I try to install all the dependencies using `bower install` I get an error: `ENOTFOUND Package gulp-concat not found`

When I installed *gulp-concat* using `npm install -g gulp-concat` I got another error while running `bower install`: `ENOTFOUND Package gulp-bower not found`

I could probably install each of the dependencies manually and then build the project. However shouldn't `bower install` download and install all the dependencies for me

**EDIT:**
Here is my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "PDFSign.js",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "PDFSign.js is a JavaScript library that signs a PDF in the browser.",
  "authors": [
    "Thomas Bocek"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": [
    "src/js/main.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "forge": "~0.6.38"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "event-stream": "^3.3.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.11",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-run": "^1.6.12",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.22",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.9.0"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

There is no package.json in my project

Comment: Can you post your bower.json and package.json?

Comment: wow... get off bower. The deprecation messages literally say "your app my stop working at anytime". Get a little dirty today and migrate to npm

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate. Bower was a big step forward for front end dependency management and had some nice properties, but a quick look at their github page suggests that it's nearing abandonware status.

Comment: yeah bower is off but this is for who still maintaining old project or not yet move from bower https://stackoverflow.com/a/27640865/2368696

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to use https://github.com/Communication-Systems-Group/pdfsign.js/tree/master

I think, unfortunately, that project is no longer maintained as the last commit was done over two years ago.

Even then I'm not sure it ever worked, there are no links to automated builds that I can see.

`gulp-bower` indeed does not exist, https://bower.io/search/ returns nothing for that package :(

You might need to find a different solution to your issue, maybe this would work? https://www.npmjs.com/package/commonpdf